# Maximum size of executable on 32-bit machine

Tags: operating-system

What is the maximum size of executable we can run on 32-bit processor?Assuming that we have an infinite hard disk.Also on what all parameters it depends upon.

Comment: What's the address space size of that cpu? 32 bits or can it be larger?

Comment: This is OS and potentially architecture-dependent.

Comment: You can realistically expect around 1.2-1.3GB under 32bit Windows and 2-2.5GB under 32bit Linux, since the former defaults to a 2/2 split and the latter defaults to a 3/1 split between user and kernel address space (that is regardless of PAE, because virtual addresses are still only 32 bits). So in theory, you would have 2GB vs. 3GB, but you'll lose some of that for shared libraries and other things that necessarily take away and fragment address space. You can boot Windows with a special switch too, in that case your application will have a 3/1 split, supposed it says that it is "3G aware".

Comment: Larger than you'll ever need.

Answer (score 3):

In practice that would depend upon the limitations of the OS and the instruction-set-architecture used by the processor.

However, since you don't mention any specific hardware or software and allow infinite disk space, it sounds like you are more interested in what is theoretically possible versus what might happen in practice.  In theory the limit would be no larger than 2^32 *instructions* (so the absolute maximum file size will be a function of the average instruction size, which will depend upon your instruction set) assuming that the theoretical 32-bit processor uses a 32-bit instruction pointer, because that is the greatest number of distinct instructions that the processor can address.  Any more than that, and there would exist instructions that the CPU could not reference or jump to given its limitations as a 32-bit device.

Of course, arriving at a 32-bit platform that could actually run a program with 2^32 instructions in it would be quite difficult.  The maximum amount of addressable RAM would be 4GB, and that has to be shared between the program's executable instructions, data, and the operating system's code and data as well.  So you would need an operating system that could page in/out not just data but a program's executable instructions as well.  This would need to happen in real-time as the program executes, such that if the program tries to do something like `jmp 0x10000000` and instruction '0x10000000' isn't in memory yet the OS catches the access attempt and pulls the requested instruction into some unused memory location and updates the instruction pointer as appropriate before allowing execution to continue.

Of course, executable files can have non-executable data embedded within them, so in that sense the theoretical maximum executable size is essentially infinite because even if you already have 2^32 instructions you can always add more data so long as you don't also add any additional executable instructions and so long as your operating system and executable format are designed to allow for arbitrarily large data sections.

Comment: Why does the number of instructions matter? (And not also the size of instructions) If I think of a bunch of instructions in a file, which can jump between position in this file, it seems like size matters too.